# Being redirected to IIS7 page

Tags: internet, redirection, iis-7

When I try to access another computer across my home network through a browser by using its ip address I get routed to an iis7 page that says iis7 and then welcome in a bunch of languages.
Any help?

Comment: Are you trying to access the file system on the other computer or a web site on the other computer?

Comment: What do you expect to see?

Answer (score 3):

That is expected behavior and everything is working correctly, if the site is not configured.

If you want to get rid of IIS, then you should go to control panel->programs and features-> operating system components (or something like that), find IIS (Internet Information Services) on the list and uncheck it. That was for Vista/7. On XP, it's on add/remove programs.

Answer (score 0):

Enable sharing on the machine you are trying to access. Then go to **Start** >> **run**  and type `\\ipaddress`.
When you try it from the browser it goes to the webserver on the remote machine and will not list the file on the system.

Answer (score 0):

This is because IIS by default runs on port 80 as a webserver, so I'm guessing you're either connecting to port 80 or not specifying a port when connecting, which defaults to connecting to port 80 (assumably by a web browser by the sound of it).

If this is unexpected behaviour, you can disable IIS.

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem today with the Tally T2365 printer. We changed the speed of the network connection from 100 Mb to 10 Mb. Not sure if that helped. We had the printer connected to a PC and both devices connected to a small switch. I power cycled the switch but that did not seem to help.

When we disconnected the switch from the LAN the normal web page finally came up and we were able to access the web page normally.

When I reconnected the switch to the LAN, again it failed.

Using the command prompt we found that the dynamic IP address was assigned to another device at the same time it was assigned to the printer. Now that surprised me since I already removed the device from the DHCP server.

So bottom line, if you see the IIS, try to isolate the printer from the rest of your network and see if that helps. It might be an IP conflict.